# loading time of IDependencyResolver.GetService() is too long

Tags: asp.net-mvc

The loading time of my website (asp.net mvc 4) is too long when it runs on the server, on my local machine it loads very fast!

I installed Glimpse for MVC to see what is happening. Glimpse trace tab shows that it is taking **12879 ms** for 'IDependencyResolver.GetService' to load.

The full message is:

> IDependencyResolver.GetService()
>   = ASP._Page_Views_Cagegories_GetByCity_cshtml

The server is dedicated server and should be strong enough.
Does anyone can advise what can I do to solve this?

Page url: http://2send.co.il/City/%D7%A2%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%94

Thanks.

Comment: View and Url was added. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly what changed on my server but the problem was solved after I run windows update. 
Among the other updates, I saw framework 4 update so I guess that's it!